# Radio group layout design in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to create the radio group as shown in diagram. Two thing i don`t know how to implement

1) the hint string below Main String(Ex: here 1 Minutes ,below some description is provided) , i don`t know how to put the description under the string.

2)separator line between two radio button. How to describe such separator line.

I don`t know whether it is possible or not.Anyone suggest some idea here.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Throben is right. You have to create a custom ListView. See the example of Custom List View [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse.html). or at [Vogella Articles](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

Answer (score 1):

For me, this looks like a ListView with custom ViewAdapter. In that case you can define the description text as you wish...